# Open pages its css and database parallel

Tags: html, parallel-processing, parallel-port

I have big `database`s that contain large no of tables and have `PHP/HTML` file with `java script` and `css` in separate folders.Now I want is to make my page load faster when user navigates through our page then the content on database, its `css` and `PHP/HTML` file that run parallel. It means there is no blockage of any stream of file or one by one each file is opening which take lots of time. Each work separates and assigns at one place to make page what is it mean for? So how can we achieve if it is there is any code that allows all file work in parallel including database?

Comment: I'm sorry, what? We usually have a lot of patience with non-english speakers but this is very difficult to understand. Could you try and rephrase, and make your question more concise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place all your `<script>` tags at the bottom of your `<body>` tag. According to Yahoo's [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html/).

> The problem caused by scripts is that they block parallel downloads. The HTTP/1.1 specification suggests that browsers download no more than two components in parallel per hostname. If you serve your images from multiple hostnames, you can get more than two downloads to occur in parallel. While a script is downloading, however, the browser won't start any other downloads, even on different hostnames.

You cannot do the same for for your stylesheets. Not only is it not W3C-complaint, but it actually won't help.

> While researching performance at Yahoo!, we discovered that moving stylesheets to the document HEAD makes pages appear to be loading faster. This is because putting stylesheets in the HEAD allows the page to render progressively.

---

On a side-note, if it's taking that much time to load your pages, also look into your PHP and SQL queries. Try to optimize those as well.

Comment: I mean some page load slow due to interaction with databases so how can we make it faster

Comment: That has nothing to do with your CSS and JavaScript. That, my friend, is a totally different problem that deserves its own StackOverflow question with plenty of code samples. If and when you do, I'd suggest finding a specific problem (query, algorithm, etc) and ask about it, not just "My page is slow. Help me."